# c++ boost property tree not escaping characters

Tags: c++, json, boost

I'm using the boost library's property tree and parse_json to parse json from a string, which contains some **escaped** characters

i.e. I have a json string that looks like this

```
"{\"ops\":{\"text\":\"\\n\"}}"
```

note that the newline character is properly escaped into ascii characters \ and n

However, when I call parse_json function with the stringstream containing the above json string, from the output I get an actual newline character, instead of \n

And if I replace the \\n with \\0 it is even worse, calling parse_json() will cause the program to immediately exit

Is this the default behaviour? Is there anything I can do to make it parse these characters?

**EDIT:**

When I put it in a file the escaped characters stay as is, but only if I use stringstream then it explodes.

Comment: That's because that's a newline character in a JSON string, so it's not literally backslash-`n`.

Comment: Wait I'm not getting it. How is blackslash-backslash-n still a newline character? Do you mean that it is interpreting it as backslash newline? I don't think this is the case since I hardcoded the string to test

Comment: There's two layers of escaping here: C++ and JSON. If it was literally a backslash-`n` sequence (two characters) it'd show up as `\\\n` here. If you output that string instead of debugging it you'd see it's just `\n` one layer in, and a newline once the final parsing occurs.

Comment: You are right, thank you